# pug use generated svg string

Tags: html, node.js, svg, pug

I'm trying to insert an SVG in my pug template but doesn't work properly.
I'm using r6operators from marcopixel which offer a function operator.toSVG() which returns the XML string of an SVG.

When I do this :

```
p some text #{operator.name}
      #{operator.toSVG()}
```

I get the image correctly but &lt and &gt staying around:

```
<p>some text Gridlock&lt;<svg  --- all the SVG content &gt;
</p>
```

if I try to put it in an SVG line like :

```
p some text #{operator.name}
    svg  #{operator.toSVG()}
```

I get something like :

```
<p> some text</p>
<svg>"<svg ---all the content</svg>"</svg>
```

I checked for some mixin templates or the SVG use but they take a href and not a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `operator.toSVG()` returns `<svg>...</svg>`, you have a couple of options:

1. Use [piped text](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html#piped-text) and [unescaped string interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#string-interpolation-unescaped):

   ```
   - const operator = { name: 'Gridlock', toSVG: () => '<svg>...</svg>' }

   p some text #{operator.name}
     | !{operator.toSVG()}
   ```
2. Use [unescaped buffered code](https://pugjs.org/language/code.html#unescaped-buffered-code):

   ```
   - const operator = { name: 'Gridlock', toSVG: () => '<svg>...</svg>' }

   p some text #{operator.name}
     != operator.toSVG()
   ```
3. Use a mix of options 1 and 2:

   ```
   - const operator = { name: 'Gridlock', toSVG: () => '<svg>...</svg>' }

   p
     | some text #{operator.name}
     != operator.toSVG()
   ```

Result in all three cases:

```html
<p>some text Gridlock<svg>...</svg></p>
```

Two variations:

1. ```
   - const operator = { name: 'Gridlock', toSVG: () => '<svg>...</svg>' }

   p
     | some text #{operator.name}
     | !{operator.toSVG()}
   ```
2. ```
   - const operator = { name: 'Gridlock', toSVG: () => '<svg>...</svg>' }

   p.
     some text #{operator.name}
     !{operator.toSVG()}
   ```

Result in both cases (notice the difference in whitespace):

```html
<p>some text Gridlock
  <svg>...</svg></p>
```